# Showing Markdown-encoded blog posts with Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug, markdown

Hello,

I have been trying to learn Node with Express for about a week now. So far I got the basics of how to build MVC on top of it, and using JavaScript proved easier and cleaner than I would have ever gotten with another server language (except Python, maybe). But let's get into one of my first problems and one of a few I couldn't solve myself.

I'm using the Jade templating engine and I love it. I love how simple it is to input Markdown into the template. You just say `:markdown` and it's there!

But then I got into a problem. It's all easy to parse and print Markdown, however how am I supposed to display a blog post, for example, that's been stored as Markdown text in the database, on screen? I tried:

```jade
each entry in posts
    h1 #{entry.title}
    :markdown
        #{entry.text}
    div#post-footer
        #{entry.date}
```

But the # gets parsed as a Markdown header, not a Jade directive. How do I make it so I can display Markdown properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var md = require('marked');

res.render('template', {md: md, markdownContent: markdownContent};
```

then inside the template use
    div!= md(markdownContent);

Comment: Well, at least it prints out now, but it prints the `=` as well. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry my jade is a bit rusty I've been neckdeep in APIs for a while, try removing the = I thought it was necessary but it may not be inside the filter

Comment: Without the = it's just like I tried in my question. Won't work either.

Comment: The only thing that would be left then is to pass in the function to the view. I'll update my answer to reflect the needed code

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought I should do then. Parse Markdown before the template. Thanks for the help!